# Is there a specification for the OracleDB protocol?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Essentially, is there a public (or dubiously sourced) document of the OracleDB protocol works. Like this:

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html

Oracle just provides a binary blob, and I want to make an asyncio connector for it.

Comment: Look for [Oracle TNS Protocol](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/layers.htm).  Last I heard, the "wire protocols" for Oracle were *not* publicly documented.  Here's an old post: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/615450/documentation-of-oracle-wire-protocol